# modulo operator null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my java snippet in Android Studio.

```
public static void makepack(Card[] pack, int[] a, int[] size) {

    for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 1;
        int High = 53;
        int k = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

        // 1st 13 are diamonds, then hearts, then clubs and then spades
        if (!inarray(a, k, size[0])) {
            pack[i - 1].num = (k % 13) + 1;
            pack[i - 1].type = (k / 13) + 1;
            a[size[0]] = k;
            size[0]++;
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Users\nhar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar;C:\Users\nhar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res;C:\Users\nhar\AndroidStudioProjects\MindicoatCardGame\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug;C:\Users\nhar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\22.1.1\support-annotations-22.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nhar\AndroidStudioProjects\MindicoatCardGame\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\22.1.1\jars\libs\internal_impl-22.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nhar\AndroidStudioProjects\MindicoatCardGame\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\22.1.1\res;C:\Users\nhar\AndroidStudioProjects\MindicoatCardGame\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\22.1.1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\nhar\AndroidStudioProjects\MindicoatCardGame\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res;C:\Users\nhar\AndroidStudioProjects\MindicoatCardGame\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.example.nihar.mindicoatcardgame.MainFunction
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.nihar.mindicoatcardgame.MainFunction.makepack(MainFunction.java:222)
    at com.example.nihar.mindicoatcardgame.MainFunction.main(MainFunction.java:244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Process finished with exit code 1
The exception is at the (%13) line. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The object in `pack` at index `i-1` that you try to access a `num` member of is probably `null`.

Comment: what is doing `inarray()` ??

Comment: it is checking whether the element is there in the array or not..

public static boolean inarray(int[] a, int x, int size) {
        int count = 0;
        if(size==0){return false;}
        else{
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (a[i] == x) {
                count = 1;
            }
        }

        }
        return count != 0;

    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that can cause a NPE on that line is if `pack[i - 1]` is null.

That's what you need to fix. The modulo is fine.

Regarding your comment, you probably want this...

```
if (!inarray(a, k, size[0])) {
    pack[i - 1] = new Card();
    pack[i - 1].num = (k % 13) + 1;
    pack[i - 1].type = (k / 13) + 1;
    a[size[0]] = k;
    size[0]++;
} else {
    i--;
}
```

Better still would be to give Card a constructor that took num and type, then you could change the three `pack[i - 1]` lines into one.

Comment: Card[] pack1= new Card[13];
        Card[] pack2= new Card[13];
        Card[] pack3= new Card[13];
        Card[] pack4= new Card[13];
        int[] dont_repeat = new int[52];


         int size1[]={0};
        makepack(pack1,dont_repeat,size1);
        makepack(pack2,dont_repeat,size1);
        makepack(pack3,dont_repeat,size1);
        makepack(pack4,dont_repeat,size1);



It has to be null initially, I want to set a value initially to the num and type using makepack function,  so what can I do?

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you a potential solution. Hope it helps

Comment: That is not helping. I got the following error:
cannot be referenced from static context
I have already declared Card[] arrays in the main function as  
Card[] pack1= new Card[13];

Comment: new Card[13] creates a new array that can hold Cards, but it doesn't create the Card objects. It'll just be full of nulls. As you're seeing.

Comment: The static context issue you now have is because your makepack method is static. It's a whole different issue.

Comment: So what should I do for the error:
cannot be referenced from static context

Comment: At the risk of sounding a little rude, I'd suggest you google it.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake was that the type of class Card was not static

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure of your inputs, then what is the most likely is that a[i-1] is null. You could simply fix it by adding pack[i - 1] = new Card(); (if it doesn't erase other data of course).

Comment: That is not helping. I got the following error: cannot be referenced from static context I have already declared Card[] arrays in the main function as Card[] pack1= new Card[13];

Comment: As said in the commentaries above, new Card[13] creates the array but not the object Card[i] inside. As for the static issue it is because your function is made static, it's another problem! Hope you could deal with it properly =)